# The intersection of $[0,x)$ where $0<x\leq 1$ is $\{0\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I proved $\{0\}$ is contained in the intersection of $[0,x)$ where $0< x \leq 1$.  But how do I show the reverse inclusion?

Comment: Oh ok I get it. You mean $\cap \{[0,x) : 0 < x \leq 1\}$.

Comment: Well, clearly the intersection is contained in $[0,1]$. If there was an $0 < y \leq 1$ such that $y$ was in the intersection, then you could find $0 < x < y$ for which $y \notin [0,x)$, a contradiction. Therefore the intersection is also contained in $\{0\}$.

Comment: @Nameless, I think you mean $[0,x) = \{y : 0 \leq y < x\}$.

Comment: THANK YOU!!! Now I got it ! Thanks so much for your help :-)

Comment: @AntonioVargas, yes thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $0\in[0,x),\forall x\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}$. Thus $\{0\}\subseteq \cap\{[0,x):0<x\leq 1\}$. Now we want to show no other number is in the intersection. Notice that $\forall c<0$, $c\not\in[0,x)\forall x$. For the other side, assume $\exists c>0$ such that $c\in\cap\{[0,x):0<x\leq 1\}$. Then $\forall x>0,c\in[0,x)$. But if $x=\frac{c}{2}$, then $c>x\Rightarrow c\not\in[0,x)$. Contradiction.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to mark this as the answer by clicking the checkmark to the left of my answer. You can also up vote or down vote answers by pressing the up or down arrows.

Comment: How kind you are. I checked and voted up your answer. Thank U !!